# Aim of user reputation leagues

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

What are the **objectives** of user reputation league?
One more point,does **Meta SO** reputation points are outside of that reputation league?

Comment: You can select what view to use - weekly, monthly, yearly or all.

Comment: The default changes based on how much data has been collected for the current week, month, quarter, year, or all-time period.

Comment: I also don't see how this is asking about the _aim_ of the reputation leagues, just about the default view.

Comment: Ok, i got that..@Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point why the leagues exist is simply that people are interested in seeing these stats. They like to see how much reputation they earned and how that compares to others. There are no deeper consequences to doing well or not in the reputation leagues.

The leagues come in several different time intervals, you can choose what you want to view by clicking the tabs on the top right of the league listing.

Comment: And,does Meta SO reputation points are outside of that reputation league?

Comment: @ridoy: Meta SO has [its own leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta-stackoverflow).

Comment: So, where are the links to these rep leagues?